# How could an event received in a callback for addEventListener be null?

Tags: typescript, dom-events

```js
input!.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.value);
});
```

TS compiler claims that `event` might be `null`. How could this be? By definition, this is a callback function that will be invoked whenever there is a `keyup` event.

I understand that this can be easily resolved with: `(event.target as HTMLSelectElement).value`. I'm not asking about a solution for this. I am curious as to what TS is.

Why/how can `event` be `null` inside a callback function for that event?

Comment: What is input? where do define it?

Comment: I suppose it could be possible to have an event which does not return anything? Typescript is guarding you against a failure here but not in your use case as `keyup` will return an event, so I suppose it's not so obvious. You may have a custom event which doesn't return a value as `addEventListener` isn't locked down to the browser's own events.

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi We are just pretending that there is a legit `input` in our HTML that we previously `querySelect`ed, for example.

Comment: @JamesHyde Ok, so TS doesn't realize what a `'keyup'` is then, specifically. .

Comment: @CodeFinity I would assume that to be correct, yes.

Answer (score 4):

The `EventTarget` type does not inherit from `HTMLElement` by default because html elements **are not the only** things that can be event targets.

Based on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget)

> Element, Document, and Window are the most common event targets, but other objects can be event targets, too. For example XMLHttpRequest, AudioNode, AudioContext, and others.

So if your `input` is `HTMLElement` the `EventTarget` must not be null and you already have solution (`(event.target as HTMLSelectElement).value`).

But as I said `EventTarget` is a more abstract interface than `Element` and in typescript it is in `EventTarget | null` type.

```
Event.target: EventTarget | null
```